# Import XML beans file from another module?

Tags: xml, spring, apache, javabeans

I am using multi-module Spring Project built using Apache Maven. I have some XML beans located in the resources folder of the module (1). I wanna to import them into another XML beans file which is located in module (2).

What I know, is that I have to use:

```
<import resource="" />
```

What is the correct way to write the path in the resource attribute? With examples if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<import resource="classpath:resources/beans-config.xml" />
```

The XML file should be in `WEB-INF/resources` folder of the referenced module(1).

Check out the note in [Composing XML-based configuration metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import).

Of course to be able to reference a classpath resource from another module, you have to add a dependency section in module 2's pom.xml like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>module1.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>module-1-artifact-id</artifactId>
        <version>module1.version</version>
    </dependency>
```

Module 1 jar will be in classpath when module 2 app is run, or be packaged into war if module 2 is a webapp.

Comment: How does the import tag knows that the bean file is located into module(1) ? you don't mention anything related to that module in your path ! 

The official documentation is so poor covering the topic of this part !